# Построить линейный список из входной последовательности чисел. Удалить из него все числа, кроме простых

Tags: c++, алгоритм, односвязный-список

Не понимаю, где ошибка, помогите найти и решить задание.

```
#include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<locale.h>
    using namespace std;
     struct  node     {
     int inf;
    node *next;
     };
    int main()
    {
    setlocale(0,"");
        node *r, *fr = NULL, *er=NULL;    // fr – указатель на головной элемент списка.
    // er – указатель на последний элемент списка.
     // r – указатель для формирования нового узла списка.
     node *rp; int a, b;             // a – переменная для записи целых чисел.
     FILE *f;
    f = fopen("t.dat","r");   // Начало формирования списка.
    do   // Начало цикла ввода чисел из файла.
     {      fscanf(f,"%d", &a);  // Ввод числа из файла.
    r = new node;              // Создаем новый элемент списка.
    // Выделяем  память для нового элемента.
     r->inf = a; // Инициализируем поле inf нового элемента списка.
    r->next = NULL;   // Инициализируем поле указателя нового элемента
    //списка.
    if (fr == NULL) // Проверяем: список существует или нет. Если
     // fr = NULL, то списка нет.
       fr = r;                // Поэтому новый элемент объявляем головным.
    else    // Если список существует, то
       er -> next = r;       // новый элемент присоединяем к списку.
    er = r;
    }  // Новый элемент объявляем последним.
    while (!feof(f));    // Конец цикла ввода чисел из файла.
    fclose(f);   // Конец формирования списка.
    // Вывод списка на экран.#include <conio.h>

    cout << "\tСформирован список:\n\n";
     r = fr;
    while (r != NULL)   // Пока не дошли до последнего элемента списка.
     {  cout << r -> inf << "  ";    // Вывод информации из поля inf элемента,
    // адрес которого  находится в указателе r.
       r = r -> next;                       // Переход к следующему элементу списка.
    // Для этого из поля next текущего элемента списка
     // в указатель r пересылаем адрес на следующий элемент.
     }
     r=fr;
     rp=r;
     while (r->next != NULL)   // Пока не дошли до последнего элемента списка.
     {
         for (int i=1;i<r->inf;i++){
            if (r->inf%i==0 && i!=1 && i!=r->inf) {
                    rp=r;
                    r=r->next;
                    cout<<"\n3\n";
                    cout<<rp;
                    break;
            }
            else{
                if (r==fr) {
                        fr=r->next;
                        delete rp;
                        rp=fr;
                        r=fr;
                        cout<<"\n1\n";
                        break;
                }
                else {
                    rp->next=r->next;
                    delete r;
                    r=rp->next;
                    cout<<"\n2\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        cout<<r;
     }
     }
      r=fr;
     while (r != NULL)
     {
       cout << r -> inf << "  ";
       r = r -> next;
     }
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Трассируйте, отлаживайте.

Comment: Так а что именно не так? Где ошибка?

Comment: @Маришка Напишите отдельную функцию, которая проверяет, является ли число простым. Так ваш код по удалению узлов упростится.

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow Спасибо:3

Answer (score 3):

Данный цикл по удалению узлов из списка, которые не содержат простые числа

```
 r=fr;
 rp=r;

 while (r->next != NULL)   // Пока не дошли до последнего элемента списка.
 {
     for (int i=1;i<r->inf;i++){
        if (r->inf%i==0 && i!=1 && i!=r->inf) {
                rp=r;
                r=r->next;
                cout<<"\n3\n";
                cout<<rp;
                break;
        }
        else{
            if (r==fr) {
                    fr=r->next;
                    delete rp;
                    rp=fr;
                    r=fr;
                    cout<<"\n1\n";
                    break;
            }
            else {
                rp->next=r->next;
                delete r;
                r=rp->next;
                cout<<"\n2\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    cout<<r;
 }
 }
```

не имеет смысла. Во первых `fr` может быть равно `NULL`, и тогда вычисление условия `r->next != NULL` приведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Во-вторых, `Fr->next` в свою очередь может быть равно `NULL`, и тогда вы не сможете проверить, содержит ли единственный узел списка простое число или нет.

Далее вы неправильно проверяете, является ли число простым. Например, число 2 является простым, а число 1 не является простым.

Поэтому вам лучше написать отдельную функцию, которая будет проверять, является ли число простым или нет. В результате у вас код упростится, и его будет легче читать.

Условия `if_else` должны проверяться уже после выполнения цикла `for`, а не при каждой его итерации.

**EDIT:** Фугкция, которая проверяет, является ли положительное число простым может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже.

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime( int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value > 2 && value % 2 );

    for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= value / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % i;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 100;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( is_prime( i ) ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

При использовании этой функцию цикл `while`  может выглядеть как

```
while ( r != NULL )
{
    if ( not is_prime( r->inf ) )
    {
        // удаляем узел
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // просто переходим к следующему узлу
        rp = r;
        r = r->next;        
    }
}
```

Следует идентификаторам давать значащие имена, чтобы читающему ваш код было понятно, что они означают. Такие идентификаторы, как `fr` или `er`, которые вы используете, трудно назвать понятными.

Также следует объявлять переменные в наименьшей области видимости. Иначе объявления многочисленных переменных может только запутывать читающего ваш код.

Если использовать ваш подход, то программа может выглядеть следующим образом, Только в ней я ввожу данные в список не из файла, а просто использую натуральный ряд чисел.

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime( int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value > 2 && value % 2 );

    for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= value / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % i;
    }

    return prime;
}

struct node
{
    int inf;
    node *next;
};

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;  

    const int N = 100;

    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        node *current = new node { i, nullptr };

        if ( head == nullptr ) head = current;
        else tail->next = current;

        tail = current;
    } while ( i++ != N );

    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->inf << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    node *previous = head, *current = head;
    while ( current != nullptr )
    {
        if ( not is_prime( current->inf ) )
        {
            if ( current == head )
            {
                head    = current->next;
                delete current; 
                current  = head;
                previous = head;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = previous->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->inf << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while ( head != nullptr )
    {
        node *current = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete current;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль выглядит следующим образом

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Однако этот подход по удалению узлов из списка нельзя назвать удачным. Почему? Потому что в общем алгоритме рассматриваются частные случаи: является ли удаляемый узел головным узлом списка.

Программирование - это искусство обобщения. Чем больше в программе рассматривается частных случаев, тем такая программа больше подвержена ошибкам, а также читающим код программы трудно уловить общую идею. Ему также придется тратить свое время на копание в этих частностях, чтобы понять, что же там делается. И такие программы сложнее поддерживать и модифицировать.

Поэтому следует писать так программы, чтобы избегать частностей, когда в них нет на самом деле необходимости. Нужно выбирать более обобщенный алгоритм, который не перегружен всякими частными случаями, проще говоря, в котором меньше различных `if-else` предложений.

В вашей программе можно использовать другой подход по удалению узлов из односвязного списка. Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime( int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value > 2 && value % 2 );

    for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= value / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % i;
    }

    return prime;
}

struct node
{
    int inf;
    node *next;
};

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    node *tail = nullptr;   

    const int N = 100;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        node *current = new node { i, nullptr };

        if ( head == nullptr ) head = current;
        else tail->next = current;

        tail = current;
    } 

    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->inf << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( node **current = &head; *current != nullptr; )
    {
        if ( not is_prime( ( *current )->inf ) )
        {
            node *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        std::cout << current->inf << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while ( head != nullptr )
    {
        node *current = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete current;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Как видно, при удалении узлов никакой частный случай, является ли узел головным, не рассматривается, так как алгоритм удаления является одинаковым для всех узлов.

В связи со всем сказанным будет интересно почитать дискуссию на одном сайте в теме [Что такое хорошо, а что такое плохо](http://www.rsdn.org/forum/flame.comp/6596405) Там дается ссылка на выступление автора операционной системы Linux Линуса Торвальдса, где он, в частности, высказал свое мнение по двум фрагментам некоего условного кода, связанного также со списком.

Так, вот, участники этого форума, которые считают себя профессионалами, во-первых, даже и не осознали, что тот пример кода условный и предназначен продемонстрировать идею. А также, во-вторых, и не поняли эту идею, то есть что имеет в виду Линус, когда один фрагмент кода считает лучше другого.

А Линус имеет в виду именно то, что я написал здесь: старайтесь писать обобщенный код, избегая ненужных частностей, которые лишь будут перегружать программу и тем самым размывать главное и второстепенное, делая более сложным увидеть главную суть алгоритма.:)

Comment: А нельзя ли прямо ссылку на мнение Линуса, а то я что-то заблудился толи в этом форуме, то ли на страничке уже с Линусом.

Comment: @avp https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux

Comment: А, так там слушать надо... (терпеть не могу это повальное увлечение)

Answer (score 0):

Вот функция для определения является ли число простым:

```
#include <math.h>
bool IsPrime (int In){
    if(In==1)
        return false;
    if(In==2)
        return true;
    if(In%2==0) //проверяем четное ли число
        return false; //если да то оно не простое
    //если нет, продолжим проверку
    int test=3;
    int stop=(int)sqrt(In)/2;//добудем корень
    //К примеру число 121 (это 11*11) надо поделить на 11 и узнаем что 121 не простое
    //А еще раз разделить на 2 потому как будем проверять
    //делением только на нечетные (ведь если число нечетное, то оно не поделится на четное)
    for(int i=0;i<stop;i++){
        if(In%test==0)
            return false;
        test+=2;//идем по нечетным числам начиная с 3
    }
    terurn true
}
```

А дальше:

```
while (r != NULL){
    if(IsPrime(r->inf)){
        //что делать если число простое
    }
    else{
        //что делать если число не простое
        //учтите, что у вас может быть всего один узел списка
        //или простым окажется только один узел списка
        //или простых чисел не окажется в списке вообще
    }
    r = r->next;
}
```

Comment: `int stop=(int)In/2/2;` - такого я еще не видел

Comment: Можно и просто на 4 поделить. :)

Comment: останавливаться можно на корне из `In`

Comment: Почему? Где почитать об этом подробней? Или если можно обоснование вкратце опишите.

Comment: `int test=3; for(int i=0;i<stop;i++){ ... test+=2; }` - жесть.

Comment: @Илья - Потому что в этом месте два делителя уравниваются.

Comment: @Igor да, натупил.

Answer (score 0):

Односвязный список, это простая структура данных, в которую можно легко вставлять новые элементы в начало списка (или после заданного элемента) и очевидным способом последовательно их обрабатывать.

Часто для работы с односвязным списком даже не требуется писать вспомогательные функции (особенно, если это не повторяющиеся действия), простые манипуляции со списком легко записываются непосредственно в коде, реализующем логику программы.

Например, вставка в список нового элемента после элемента, на который указывает `cur`:

```
newnode->next = cur->next;
cur->next = newnode;
```

Несколько образцов кода для работы с односвязными списками.

Вот очень простой цикл построения односвязного списка (предполагая, что порядок не важен, строим список в обратном порядке (как стек)).

```
  node *list = 0;
  int n;

  while (cout << "Enter N: ", cin >> n) {
    node *p = new node;
    p->next = list;
    p->inf = n;
    list = p;
  }
```

Если порядок важен, то можно либо реверсировать весь построенный ранее список

```
  for (node *p = list, *t = list = 0; t = p;) {
    p = p->next;
    t->next = list;
    list = t;
  }
```

либо завести еще один указатель, который всегда будет смотреть на последний элемент в списке и строить список так:

```
  node *list = 0, *tail;
  int n;

  while (cout << "Enter NUM: ", cin >> n) {
    node *p = new node;
    p->inf = n;
    p->next = 0;

    if (list)
      tail->next = p;
    else
      list = p;
    tail = p;
  }
```

Кстати, иногда удобно представлять односвязный список структурой, которая содержит указатели на первый и последний элементы списка.

```
struct s_list {
   s_list *list, *tail;
};
```

Только надо не забывать правильно модифицировать оба эти указателя при удалении элементов и вставке новых.

Вот цикл печати списка

```
  for (node *c = list; c; c = c->next)
    cout << c->inf << '\n';
```

А вот простой цикл для удаления выбираемых элементов односвязного списка
(обычно наибольшие трудности возникают именно с удалением в процессе итераций по списку)

```
  for (node **p = &list, *c = *p; c;)
    if (deleit(c)) {
      *p = c->next;
      delete c;
      c = *p;  
    } else {
      p = &c->next;
      c = c->next;
    }
```

В нем `node **p` всегда адресует указатель, который ссылается на проверяемый (и потенциально удаляемый) элемент списка.

Вместо `deleit()` пишете свою функцию, например определяющую, является ли число простым.

И наконец, код для удаления всех узлов списка и обнуления указателя на него

```
  while (list) {
    node *t = list->next;
    delete list;
    list = t;
  }
```

Естественно, если такие фрагменты встречаются в коде многократно, то имеет смысл оформлять их в виде функций.